# Angular 4 forEach() on component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

```
rowData: any = [{
  'title': 'Product' as string,
  'qty': null as number,
  'material_margin': null as number,
  'material_unit_rate': null as number,
  'labour_unit_rate': null as number
}];

rowData.forEach( item => {
  this.material_sub_total = this.material_sub_total + item.material_unit_rate*item.qty+(item.material_margin/100*item.material_unit_rate*item.qty);
});
```

I have defined an array with object in one of my component and I want to calc sub total But I get error saying duplicate identifier 'rowData'.
If possible could anyone suggest me how to use foreach or even if it is possible? I am using angular 4 created with cli.

Full code of component goes here

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { MdSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { SlimLoadingBarService } from 'ng2-slim-loading-bar';
import { LaravelService } from './../laravel.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-single-estimate-section',
  templateUrl: './single-estimate-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single-estimate-section.component.css']
})
export class SingleEstimateSectionComponent implements OnInit {

  section: any = [];
  estimate_id: number;
  section_id: number;
  laravelResponse: any;
  submitButton = false;
  buttonClicked: string;

  material_sub_total: number = 0;
  labour_sub_total: number = 0;

  rowData: Array<Object> = [{
    'title': 'Product' as string,
    'qty': null as number,
    'material_margin': null as number,
    'material_unit_rate': null as number,
    'labour_unit_rate': null as number
  }];


  rowData.forEach(item => {
    this.material_sub_total = this.material_sub_total + item.material_unit_rate * item.qty + (item.material_margin / 100 * item.material_unit_rate * item.qty);
  });


  public postForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    'title': '',
    'qty': '',
    'material_margin': '',
    'material_unit_rate': '',
    'labour_unit_rate': ''
  });

  onButtonClick(event: string) {
    this.buttonClicked = event;
  }

  onAddNewClick() {
    this.rowData.push({
      'title': '' as string,
      'qty': null as number,
      'material_margin': null as number,
      'material_unit_rate': null as number,
      'labour_unit_rate': null as number
    });
  }

  onRemoveRowClick(i: number) {
    this.rowData.splice(i, 1);
  }

  onSubmit(data) {
    let formData = this.postForm.value;
    this.laravel.post_request('/edit-estimate-section/' + this.estimate_id + '/' + this.section_id, formData).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.laravelResponse = data.json();

        if (this.laravelResponse.status == 1) {
          this.snackBar.open(this.laravelResponse.message, 'OK', { duration: 3000 });
          if (this.buttonClicked == 'update-continue') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/estimates/' + this.estimate_id + '/edit-section/' + this.section_id);
          } else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/estimates/' + this.estimate_id);
          }
        } else {
          this.snackBar.open(this.laravelResponse.message, 'OK', { duration: 6000 });
        }

      }
    );
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: Http,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private laravel: LaravelService,
    private snackBar: MdSnackBar,
    private slimLoadingBarService: SlimLoadingBarService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.slimLoadingBarService.start();

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        this.estimate_id = params.id;
        this.section_id = params.section_id;
      }
    );

    this.laravel.get_request('/get-estimate-section/' + this.estimate_id + '/' + this.section_id).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.laravelResponse = data.json();

        if (this.laravelResponse.status == 1) {
          this.section = this.laravelResponse.data;

          this.postForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          });

        } else {
          this.snackBar.open(this.laravelResponse.message, 'OK', { duration: 6000 });
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/404');
        }
        this.slimLoadingBarService.complete();

      }
    );

  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tryed `this.rowData.forEach...`. By the way i think you should use `Array.reduce` instead of `forEach`

Comment: Another option are pipes. https://github.com/fknop/angular-pipes

Comment: i used this.rowData.forEach but still not working, it suggest unexpected token on VS Code @Diego

Comment: I want to calculate on component so that afterwards I could sent to server through http post. @ThinkingMedia

Comment: try changing the type of the array from `any` to `Array` and also post full code of the class as well

Comment: I did but still got another error on VS Code itself

rowData: Array<Object> = [{
  'title': 'Product' as string,
  'qty': null as number,
  'material_margin': null as number,
  'material_unit_rate': null as number,
  'labour_unit_rate': null as number
}];

Comment: Please post full code of the class

Comment: please check, i updated question! @Mr_Perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you trying foreach before constructor that's why you got error.

your foreach should like that. this `this.countSubtotal()`; wriet int onNgInit method();

```
 countSubtotal(){
     this.rowData.forEach(item => {
        this.material_sub_total = this.material_sub_total + item.material_unit_rate * item.qty + (item.material_margin / 100 * item.material_unit_rate * item.qty);
      });
}
```

i can't understand when you store data into `rowdata` but you need to call `countSubtotal();` after store data into rowData.

```
onAddNewClick() {
    this.rowData.push({
      'title': '' as string,
      'qty': null as number,
      'material_margin': null as number,
      'material_unit_rate': null as number,
      'labour_unit_rate': null as number
    });
  this.material_sub_total  = 0;
  this.countSubtotal();
  }
```

Comment: thanks. sure thing, it works fine there. But if could i bind the calculation if array updates? can I? @Shailesh

Comment: Actually rowData is binded from frontend template. so it will have lots of array when I add from frontend. @Shailesh

Comment: @susonwaiba yes when you bind array at that time cal this function again so you value recaculated. but you need to reset material_sub_total before you call  countSubtotal() function

Comment: move all function after ngOnInit method.

Comment: But still there are fields only where I want to calc the sub total but still there is 2 dimension. its like someone can add new row or element or object to array as above mentioned. and i want to automatically update subtotal which is calculated from all the elements of array. I cant just put every input field a trigger to call calc method. Is there any other easy and comfortable way of doing it.? @shailesh

Comment: you do it  (change) event but you say above lots of input field. so i think this is better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put a random JS statement in the middle of your class. Classes contains property definitions and methods. Code goes in methods. What would a random JS statement in a class mean? When would it be executed? Who would call it?

Put your `rowData.forEach` inside a method called `calcMaterialSubtotal` or whatever, and then call it from wherever you want to call it from.

Comment: sure thing. But I want to bind array with multiple input field which can be added from frontend that means, I just can't call from all those input fields so, I need to calc it at component as binded. ? what you say.? how to do it. need suggestion ?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand your question.

Comment: let me explain: user can add more objects to array. all the elements of object have input fields. some fields gets numeric input which is needed to calculate all together. so I can't add (keydown)="calc()" on everyone of it. It may be 100s because each field get 3 4 input field. so, I need to bind array which will update colz objects are binded to input by ngModel. shall I add (keydown)="calc()" to every on of them or there is another way of doing this.